# Fixing error The type of namespace of name 'Cloud' does not exist in the namespace 'Google'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm setting up Firestore through Unity right now, and the documentation says to include

```
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;
```

in the Program.cs file. I'm getting this error however when I do so. Any idea how to fix this?

The type of namespace of name 'Cloud' does not exist in the namespace 'Google'. Are you missing an assembly reference?